# What is my code missing. no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << vals'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct twoVals
{
        int x;
    double y;
} number;

int main()
{
    number.x = 10;
    number.y = 20;

twoVals vals;
cout << vals << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Line 19: error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << vals'
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

That is the error I get. How do I fix this? Is there anything else wrong with my code? Give examples.

Comment: Well, there is no `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const twoVals&)`. Easy as that. You need to define one yourself, or simply show both members: `cout << vals.x << " " << vals.y;`. However, it seems that you just started C++ coming from C. This is a good time to grab a [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1139697) before you start developing bad habits.

Comment: Thanks, Add as a answer next time so I can upvote.

Comment: There's probably at least one duplicate of this, see the related links ;)